# How to make `NSPredicate` to ignore a some characters in searching

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

for exam:

I stored `V«003»` text in the core data `id` attribute.

If I pass the `003` or `V003` to the `NSPredicate` it should approve the search, but because of `«` and `»` characters the `NSFetchRequest` couldn't find the field.

How could I ignore `«` and `»` characters in `NSPredicate`?

Is there any `Regular Expression` way for `NSPredicate`?

Comment: You can find answer from this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34320433/how-can-i-modify-nspredicate-to-ignore-whitespaces-in-swift

Comment: Remove the unwanted characters before searching. [Check out this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32339717/3151675)

Comment: @Khushbu, It's not the answer. because of `NSFetchedResultsController` I can't use 2 steps filtering.

Comment: @the4kman, I have that bad characters in the stored data in coredata, I shouldn't change stored data because of my search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy with Regular Expression, the question mark indicates an *optional* character.

```
let pattern = "V«?003»?"
NSPredicate(format: "id MATCHES %@", pattern)
```

**Edit:**
to fix user input, I added `«?»?` between every user input characters:

```
func generatePattern(item: String) -> String {
    var str = ""
    for st in item {
        str.append(contentsOf: "«?»?")
        str.append(st)
    }
    str.append(contentsOf: "«?»?")
    return String(str)
}
```

Comment: I just have `V003` characters that user entered and the `V` char is not static. It not possible to generate pattern! right?

Comment: If the `V` is not static but `003` is then use `"\\w«?003»?"`.  `\\w` is one arbitrary alphanumeric character. Or if you want to restrict it to uppercase letters use `"[A-Z]«?003»?"`

Comment: Because of bad backend design, I think it's better to put `«?»?` between every chars. BTW, thanks for your new solution. ;-)